# Error adding codesample plugin to TinyMCE in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

- I'm using WordPress version 5.2.1.
- I've downloaded the codesample plugin, because it's not included in WordPress by default.
- I've uploaded it to the /wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins folder
- I've added a reference to prism.css and prism.js to my theme, as mentioned [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/codesample/).
- I've activated the 'Advanced TinyMCE Configuration' and updated the 'Plugins' option to include 'codesample'.

When I load a page with a TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor, it no longer renders and my console reports:

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registry' of undefined" in the codesample plugin.min.js file.

I've noticed that the WordPress version of TinyMCE is an old version - 4.8.0 (2018-06-27).  Do I need to manually update it?  Is this good practise?

I just wondered if I'm missing part of the process?

Thanks.

***UPDATE***
I've added the plugin via Functions.php as advised:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/tinymce/plugins/codesample/prism.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/tinymce/plugins/codesample/prism.js' );

function my_custom_plugins( $plugins ) {
     $plugins['codesample'] = get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js';
     return $plugins;
}
add_filter( 'mce_external_plugins', 'my_custom_plugins' );
```

But how do I go about upgrading the TinyMCE editor to v5?

Comment: As a general rule you should **never** change core WordPress files: next time you update WordPress (and you should or else you may expose your site to security holes & bugs) all modifications made to its files will be undone by the update. Instead, use the various [filter/action hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) WordPress provides so you can safely customize it and keep your changes between upgrades. And before you ask, yes, there are some hooks you can use to customize the TinyMCE editor :) Check the documentation for more details.

Comment: "But how do I go about upgrading the TinyMCE editor to v5?" is entirely a different question and you need another thread for that. I would appreciate your "answer" added to this question as I have a pop-up source code window but no language drop-down list.

Comment: I created an account at Tiny and downloaded the core product. I uploaded the coresample folder to the correct place. I then tried adding the snippets you provided (even with hard coded url paths) and it would not work. It failed to load the js files when I viewed the editor. So I gave up.

Comment: I ended up writing my own plugin - you can install it from the WordPress plugins section: https://wordpress.org/plugins/alkanecode/

Comment: My plugin fixes a few bugs too, adds inline support, proper pre/code tags, allows tabbing to indent code etc - more info here: https://www.alkanesolutions.co.uk/blog/2019/07/06/alkane-code-wordpress-code-editor-prism-syntax-highlighting/